# Limit display of a specific tag in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, tags, limit

How do I limit the results of a certain tag in Wordpress? For example, I want to only display 5 entries of the tag "Popular" in my page. Is there a script which I can put in the functions.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use like this

```
<?php
     $posttags = get_the_tags();
     $count=0;
    if ($posttags) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $count++;
    $output .= $tag->name . ' ';
    if( $count >4 ) break;  //you can limit count here
    }
   }
  echo $output;
 ?>
```